# how to cache a subset for cascading select queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, filter, bigdata, cascading

heres another database problem I stubled upon.

I have a date-range partitioned Myisam lookup table with 200M records and ~150 columns. 
On this Table I need to perform cascading SELECT-Statements to filter the data.
Output:

1. filter 126M
2. filter 110M
3. filter 40M
4. filter 5M
5. filter 100k

Every single SELECT is highly complex with regex (=no index possible) and multiple comparisons, which is why I want them to query the least amount of rows possible.

There are about 500 unique filters and around 200 constant users. Every filter needs to be run for each user, in total around 100k combinations.

Big question: 
Is there a way for each subsequent SELECT statement to query only the previous subset?

Example: 
Filter #5 should only have to query the 5M rows out of query 4 to get those 100k results. At the moment it has to scan through all 200M records.

**EDIT**
current approach: cache table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cache 
(  filter_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
user_id int(11) NOT NULL,  
lookup_id int(11) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE cache ADD PRIMARY KEY (filter_id,user_id);
```

This would contain the relation between individual data-rows from the lookup table and the filters. PLUS I'd be able to use the primary index to get all of the lookup_ids from the previous filter.

Query for subsequent filters:

```
SELECT SUM( column), COUNT(*) 
FROM cache c 
LEFT JOIN lookup_table l 
ON c.lookup_id= l.id 
WHERE c.filter_id = 1 
AND c. user_id= x 
AND l.regex_column = preg_rlike...
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should save primary key of selected records to a some kind of temporary table? On next step join that temp table with your main table.

Comment: i added my current approach which does exactly that. But is the index search and join on a huge table + small regex query faster than the "big" regex query on all records? i guess I'll have to benchmark..

Comment: I think it depends on particular data set and conditions. In my fast tests I see approximately 3 times better result for query with join. Source table ~1m records, cache table ~50k records and ~4k rows satisfied select conditions. So, yes, you have to benchmark.